# How to work with server generated HTML instead of JSON with Backbone.js or React.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, backbone-views, reactjs

Almost all guides available online talk about working with JSON that is fetched from the server. We are taking an alternative approach to this.

We are generating HTML markup with the data server side, at least on initial page request (mostly for SEO reasons), and then trying to get Backbone.js to takeover from there (for infinite scrolling, or making future POST requests, as an example), a la [Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-on-twittercom).

I have searched online for some guidance on this for over two days now but have not found anything besides this:

[SEO And Accessibility With HTML5 PushState, Part 2: Progressive Enhancement With Backbone.js](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/)

Am I missing something very obvious or is there a truly clean way of doing this with Backbone and/or Reactjs?

Comment: What problem are you having? In backbone a view can reference an existing element on your page.

Comment: What is the actual problem. Because I could show you how to load HTML loaded from the server into a view but without knowing what issues you ran into when trying this no one can help.

Comment: Not a problem per se, but we wanted to make sure if this was a good practice and if doing so was possible at all. @Johnston, could you please show me some code on how to do this with Backbone or React?

Comment: jquery `load` is made for this.

Comment: This is the problem I started solving with Reactize/Turbo-React. It's pre-pre-pre-alpha untested, so don't use in production, but it's an exploration in the direction you want. https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React, I recommend [react-quickstart](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-quickstart).

The tools it comes with make server-side rendering very simple, and the client picks up the DOM and makes it interactive.

> A minimal React project template which combines:
>
> - react-router-component to provide HTML5 History routing and navigation
> - react-async to create "asynchronous" React components
> - express to serve pre-rendered React components, assets and provide API
> - browserify to provide module system for a browser
> - npm to install and manage server-side and client-side dependencies

Comment: Is there a way to work with ReactJs when the server side language is PHP? I know I can use PECL's V8 extension but any other way to do this?

Comment: @MelMaldonado, you could proxy to a node server.